# what does Q( Q framework) mean? ( the asynchronous javascript framework)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

[**Q framework**](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) is very famous( more than 7k stars on github), could someone tell me what does Q mean?

I have googled around and checked its official doc, but not found any clue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much explained in the doc.

> The callback approach is called an “inversion of control”. A function that accepts a callback instead of a return value is saying, “Don’t call me, I’ll call you.”. **Promises *un-invert* the inversion, cleanly separating the input arguments from control flow arguments.** This simplifies the use and creation of API’s, particularly variadic, rest and spread arguments.

You might want to read more regarding [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) and how that relates to using control flow libraries like Q, and how [Promises](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/) fit in.

Comment: thanks, but what does Q stands for?  it's not an abbr, nor a metaphor... ( I have check the callback hell already... ) just curious about 'Q' this very short  name ....  ^_^

Comment: @SiweiShen **Queue** (captain obvious to the rescue).